# Replace \n with \r\n in Unix file

Tags: unix, cross-platform, sed

I'm trying to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800030/remove-carriage-return-in-unix), replacing Unix line endings with Windows line endings, so that I can [use SQL Server bcp over samba to import the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494285/can-sql-server-bcp-in-a-file-with-unix-line-endings). I have `sed` installed but not `dos2unix`. I tried reversing the examples but to no avail.

Here's the command I'm using.

```
sed -e 's/\n/\r\n/g' myfile
```

I executed this and then ran `od -c myfile`, expecting to see `\r\n` where there used to be `\n`. But there all still `\n`. (Or at least they appear to be. The output of od overflows my screen buffer, so I don't get to see the beginning of the file).

I haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have a compiler available?

Comment: What kind of a compiler?

Comment: to see the top fo the file:
    od -c filename | less

Comment: Compare with [Insert the carriage return character in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1585463).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- What is the problem with getting `dos2unix` onto the machine?
- What is the platform you are working with?
- Do you have GNU `sed` or regular non-GNU `sed`?

On Solaris, `/usr/bin/sed` requires:

```
sed 's/$/^M/'
```

where I entered the '^M' by typing <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.  The '$' matches at the end of the line, and replaces the end of line with the control-M.  You can script that, too.

Mechanisms expecting `sed` to expand '`\r`' or '`\\r`' to control-M are going to be platform-specific, at best.

Comment: This did the trick. I might be able to get dos2unix on there, but I was hoping to use existing software. I'm on AIX. I assume it's the non-GNU version. Now that you mention it I've used the control-v control-m trick in vi before, should have thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

When faced with this, I use a simple `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r\n/' filename
```

because `sed` behavior varies, and I know this works.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best portable option.  The hand-entered ^M and unreliable \r expansions above are showstoppers.

Comment: my_stupidity: using this twice creates a lot of '\r\r\n'. to repair I did `perl -pi -e 's/\r\r\n/\r\n/' filename` . Just wondering how to assure in general that a file contains no mixed mode  patterns (from the view of should be msdos) like `r\r` or `n\n`

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the `-e` option.

`$` matches the endline character. This `sed` command will insert a `\r` character before the end of line:

```
sed 's/$/\r/' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason this just sticks an r at the end of the file.

Comment: According to the info manual to GNU sed: "All the escapes introduced here are GNU extensions, with the exception of `\n'.".

Comment: My fault for not specifying the Unix flavor. I'm using AIX. +1 for being the first to point out that I should be searching for $ instead of \n.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a `\r` (aka `^M`, see Jonathan Leffler's answer)  in front of `\n` is not safe because the file might have mixed mode EOL, so then you risk ending up with some lines becomming `\r\r\n`.  The safe thing to do is first remove all '\r' characters, and then insert (a single) `\r` before `\n`.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/^M//g' ${1+"$@"} | sed 's/$/^M/'
```

Updated to use `^M`.

Comment: this is adding the string ^M at the end of each line

Answer (score 1):

```
 sed 's/\([^^M]\)$/\0^M/' your_file
```

This makes sure you only insert a \r when there is no \r before \n. This worked for me.

Comment: Wrong in so many ways, don't use this answer. This should work however: `sed -r 's/([^\r]|^)$/\1\r/' "your_file"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
echo " this is output" > input
sed 's/$/\r/g' input |od -c
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you try it this way

```
cat myfile | sed 's/\n/\r\n/g' > myfile.win
```

will work, from my understanding your just making the replacements to the console output, you need to redirect output to a file, in this case myfile.win, then you could just rename it to whatever you want.  The whole script would be (running inside a directory full of this kind of files):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find . -type f -name '*')
do
  cat $file | sed 's/\n/\r\n/g' > $file.new
  mv -f $file.new $file
done
```

Comment: well is platform specific, Jonathan Leffler's answer is better