# Insert the carriage return character in Vim

Tags: unix, vim, newline, special-characters, carriage-return

I'm editing a network protocol frame stored in a file in Unix (`\n` newlines). I need to insert the carriage return character (`U+000D` also known as `\r` or `^M`).
When I try to paste it from the clipboard (`"+p`) or type it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>-`000d`, the linefeed is inserted (`U+000A`).

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Type: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>

On Windows Use: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>q</kbd>  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> tells vi that the next character typed should be inserted literally and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd> is the keystroke for a carriage return.

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. The help can be found using `:help ins-special-keys`.

Comment: If you're using the default Windows installation then replace CTRL+V by CTRL+Q since CTRL+V is remmaped to 'paste'.

Comment: After much headbanging I'm adding this here even though it's an old question: to insert a literal CR character from a :s command, you must precede it with a backslash or else vim (7.1.314) will convert it to the end of line character appropriate for your fileformat setting.  ie enter `:s/.../\^V^M/g`.

Comment: What about `Ctrl+V` followed by `Enter`? I notice that also inserts `^M` into the text

Comment: Note that this also works for ESC as well: first, go into INSERT mode (i), then Ctrl+V ESC, and you've got yourself an ESC character.

Comment: I wanted to write ^R in vim, however could not get it to work until I tried this in insert mode <ctrl-v><ctrl-R>