# How to add a carriage return as a character to a file?

Tags: linux, unix, special-characters

I wanna have a string like:

```
blablbabla<carriage return goes here>
```

I mean the string should contain the carriage return. Is there any simple way to do it? Or if a write a program in c and use fputs with `blablabla\r`, does this do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `vim` you can enter insert mode and type 'CTRL-v CTRL-m'. That ^M is the keyboard equivalent to \r. (see [Insert the carriage return character in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585449/insert-the-carriage-return-character-in-vim))

Inserting 0x0D in a hex editor will do the task.

Answer (score 9):

`echo -ne "blablbabla\r" > /path/to/your/file`

Comment: @wonnie. You are right, requires -e switch.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SHELLVAR=$(echo -ne "blablabla\r")
```

See the `echo` man page — the `-e` option causes echo to interpret backslash escapes.

Also, at least in bash's normal edit mode, the same control-v control-m sequence works to insert a carriage return character literally; it will show as `^M`