# Ruby interpreter issue in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-1.9.3

The was running correctly:

```
C:\>ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
Hi #[pressed ENTER]
[pressed ENTER]
Hi # <~~ here Hi came as the output, as expected.

here is: "\n\n"  #<~~ here Hi came as the output, as expected.

C:\>
```

But I was surprised when this happens on my Ubuntu machine:

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -00 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'
> hi # [pressed ENTER]
> [pressed ENTER]
> hi #[pressed ENTER]
> ^C
@ubuntu:~$
```

Any suggestions what to do to make it work in Ubuntu also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me in Ubuntu:

```
% ruby -00 -e 'a = gets; puts a; puts "here is #{$/.inspect}"'                                                                        
hi

hi

here is "\n\n"
```

Looks like you're just missing the last single quote in the command.

Comment: `ruby -015 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'` could you try this?

Comment: In that case, pressing enter does nothing because it's not generating a carriage return.  However, if I use `ctrl-v`,`ctrl-m` to generate a \r, it works:

`hello
^M
hello

here is: "\r"
`

Comment: Could you tell me the source of this? what control key is for what ? I have many more to test.

Comment: All I did was Google how to generate a carriage return, found out it was `ctrl-v`,`ctrl-m`.  Tried it, it worked.

Comment: Okay....... could you give me the link where you found that `ctrl-m` please, I am goggling for `backspace` not getting the correct one. I have to run the `ruby -010 -e 'a= gets; puts a ;puts "here is: #{$/.inspect}"'`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742340/how-to-add-a-carriage-return-as-a-character-to-a-file, the accepted answer.  Unfortunately has nothing to do with what you're looking for now.  But, I'm sure you'll find what you need if you keep looking.