# How to store the character '\b' and make it be recognized by the file of c program

Tags: c, io, terminal, special-characters, literals

When I read the C Programming Language and do the exercise 1-10, there is a problem made me puzzled.

It's said that when I enter a backspace, the  character is processed by the console driver and not delivered to the program, so what I can do is create a file with embedded backspace.However, it's seemed useless no matter I directly enter '\b' or press <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>, the screen will show "\b", but when I run the program, it seems that the program will still see it as two characters '\' and 'b'. No matter what I enter, it never shows "\backspace" when I run the program.

What should I do to make the program recognize it as a character of backspace?

My codes are like following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(c=='\t')
            printf("\\t");
        else if(c=='\\')
            printf("\\\\");
        else if(c=='\b')
                 printf("\\backspace");
             else
                 putchar(c);
     }
}
```

Comment: "create a file" How did you create this file? (what text editor?)

Comment: I use vim and create a file named b.Then type the command ./a.out <b...Does it have some problems?

Comment: You have to use a [special key combination in vim to enter control characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1585463) such as backspace.  In your case, you should type `ctrl + v`, followed by `ctrl + h`.  That will enter a real backspace character.

Comment: Oh, no, it's not Ctrl +h. It's other letters and I forgot it.Now, I can't find it and know what those letters are. I'm so sorry

Comment: Well, I press Ctrl+h, and Ctrl + v, and when I　press wq, it's print that b written. But when I type the command to run the program, it still can't print \backspace.It seems that the program recognize it as a empty line and print none in that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with your code, but with the way you wrote the backspace character in your text editor.

You have to use a [special key combination in vim to enter control characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1585463) such as backspace.  In your case, you should type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>.  That should produce a real backspace character.

To see whether you have produced an actual backspace character, you can use `hexdump`:

```
$ hexdump myfile
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 20 08 77  6f 72 6c 64              |hello .world|
                            ^^
```

Notice the `08`, which is the backspace character (in C, it's denoted `\b`).

---

Another way to produce the backspace character is to simply write it via a program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "w");
    fputs("hello \bworld", f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You answer has solved my problem,it print backspace correctly.Thank you very much!

Comment: Then,could you tell me what keys should I input in Windows?

Comment: Embedding an unprintable ASCII character in the source code, like ASCII 08, is evil. Use the appropriate backslash escape sequence instead.

Comment: @MaryWee: it depends on the text editor you use. For Vim on Windows, I believe the same key sequence should work.

Comment: @200_success: there are no unprintable characters embedded in this source code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not really in your program, but, like you said, in your terminal driver.  The odd behaviour, as observed by your program, is a consequence of the Unix terminal model.

Notice that after you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you probably also have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before your program sees the <kbd>Tab</kbd> as a `\t` character.  That means that your terminal is in "cooked" mode (i.e., not raw mode).  Similarly, the terminal driver will handle <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> before your program's `getchar()` will ever get a chance to see it.

What you can do is run `stty -icanon` before launching your program.  (Alternatively, you can [do it programmatically](/q/22572983/1157100) within your program's initialization routine.)  Then, keystrokes such as <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> keypress will be instantly picked up by `getchar()`, literally.

To restore the default terminal behaviour, use `stty icanon` or `stty sane`.

Comment: I found the man page of stty and find the "stty sane", and I still puzzled that how to use it and what like the correct format. Sorry, I'm a linux newer, and could you tell me what's the correct format command when using stty icanon and stty sane?

Answer (score 2):

`Backspace` is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart) code 8.

So you could check on `c == 0x08` when reading from a file.

```
else if(c == 0x08)
    printf("\\backspace");
```

You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792812/the-backspace-escape-character-b-in-c-unexpected-behavior).

Comment: Well, I have seen it just now and understanding that program. But, it seems that it's different from mine. I just can't make the "\c" within a file can be recognized as one character when I make  the program redirect to a file named b which embedded "\b"