# I would like to add ^M at the end of all row in CSV file

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, dos2unix

I have the CSV file that contains data around 100M rows and I would like to add ^M at the end of each row because if not have a ^M I cannot load the CSV file into the table(It just load only the 1st row and then ignore another row).

I tried to add ^M with go to the end of row and press Ctrl+V and Ctrl+M and test load again then it works, but I cannot manual input ^M every row and I cannot generate the new CSV file again because it takes a very long time.

The example original
a,b,c,d
aa,bb,cc,dd

My expect
a,b,c,d^M
aa,bb,cc,dd^M

---

I tried to use 
:%s/$/^M/g and ex +"%s/$/^M/g" -cwq ITEM_1.csv

but it is like I use a enter command like this

The example original
a,b,c,d
aa,bb,cc,dd

After command, it have a blank new line, not ^M
a,b,c,d

aa,bb,cc,dd

Thank and Best Regards,

Comment: Ooh I just found the solution :s/$/\^V^M/g
reference from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585449/insert-the-carriage-return-character-in-vim

Comment: removed Orale tag.  Not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use unix2dos?
You essentially want to do the reverse of dos2unix

http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/unix2dos1.html

Comment: Wow Thank you so much.
Previously, I understand that the unix2dos only use to remove the ^M only but I just tried to use the unix2dos from your recommend and its work

Comment: but I cannot modify the large CSV file. It showed error "Value too large for defined data type."

Comment: Is your OS 32 bit?  If so, you are running into a problem with the size of your data not being able to be handled in 32-bit.  Try it on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: that is a:
isainfo -v
64-bit sparcv9 applications
        crc32c cbcond pause mont mpmul sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 camellia kasumi 
        des aes ima hpc vis3 fmaf asi_blk_init vis2 vis popc 
32-bit sparc applications
        crc32c cbcond pause mont mpmul sha512 sha256 sha1 md5 camellia kasumi 
        des aes ima hpc vis3 fmaf asi_blk_init vis2 vis popc v8plus div32 mul32

Comment: Oh, this is solaris :)  There's going to be all kinds of fun caveats.

Comment: This is likely your reason: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-1075/msgs-2215/index.html